# Other elements disapper after page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want call function javascript with Jquery. But after page is loaded, all other elements are disappeared. You can see my code here. I need your fix.

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#recentpost").each(function(){
mytext = "Food";
sticky();
});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sticky(){
document.write("<div class='sample'>"+mytext+"</div>");
}
</script>
<div id="recentpost"></div>

<div>something here disappear after loaded page</div>
```

Thank for your help

Comment: There can only be one id, so no need for `each` as in = `$("#recentpost").each(function(){`

Answer (score 7):

It's because you're using `document.write` after the page is loaded, which writes the new content to the document, effectively destroying the page.

You should be using the DOM to manipulate content, as all the HTML has been written and parsed into an object tree.

For example,

```
function sticky(){
    document.getElementById("recentpost").textContent = mytext;
}
```

---

Also, it's odd that you're using `.each()` on an ID. There can be only one on the page.

So instead of this:

```
$("#recentpost").each(function(){
    mytext = "Food";
    sticky();
});
```

You'd do this:

```
$("#recentpost").text("Food");
```

---

Or if you wanted to use your `sticky()` function, you should pass the value to the function instead of using a global variable.

```
sticky("Food");

function sticky(mytext) {
    $("#recentpost").text(mytext);
}
```

Comment: But i need to use document.write to create HTML code. For example document.write("<div class="classample">"+mytext+"</div>");

Comment: @happi: I highly recommend that you read through some tutorials to learn the basics. In the first example, you'd use `.innerHTML` instead of `.textContent()`. In the last two examples, you'd use `.html()` instead of `.text()`. Again, please take the time to learn the basics. You should be asking for help as a last resort.

Comment: Sorry. I am not developer. I just get any suggestion to use it. So, I give my ques here. I don't have much time to learn from basic.

Comment: @happi: This is a site for developers.